# Executing a SQL Server stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have problems executing my stored procedure in C# console application and I don't know what the problem is. Could you please take a look?

```
string path="";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sqlErrorMessages = new StringBuilder("Sql Exception:\n");

try
{ 
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-M3IMRLE\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = db2; Integrated security=true");

    Console.WriteLine("Enter path : ");
    path = Console.ReadLine();
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("EXECUTE main.mainproc @path='" + path + "'", conn);

    if(command!=null)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("JSON loaded");
    }  

    conn.Close();
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    sqlErrorMessages.AppendFormat("Message: {0}\n", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: First thing I notice, you never execute your command. You also declare `cmd` and `sb` without utilizing them, they can probably be removed. You should probably declare the command's CommandText to be the name of your Stored Procedure, and set the CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure, then add the path value as a SqlParameter to the command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could execute a stored procedure giving its name to the `SqlCommand` constructor and flagging the `CommandType` as a stored procedure.
Parameters are loaded in the `Parameters` collection of the command:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mainproc", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@path", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = path;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The final call to `ExecuteNonQuery` runs your stored procedure, but it is intended for procedures that runs an INSERT/UPDATE or DELETE commands, or in other words, commands that don't return data.

If your stored procedure is expected to return one or more records then you need more code:

```
....
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
   // Get data from the first field of the current record assuming it is a string
   string data = reader[0].ToString();
}
```

The `ExecuteReader` method starts retrieving your data with the `Read` call and then continue until there are records to read. Inside the loop you can retrieve the fields data indexing the reader instance (and converting the object value to the appropriate type)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called `ExecuteNonQuery` on your SqlCommand

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public DataSet GetDataSet(SqlConnection connection, string storedProcName, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

        var result = new DataSet();
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        dataAdapter.Fill(result);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.