# Passing parameters in C# to SQL Server stored procedure - too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, parameter-passing

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stpr_WPC_UpdatePOReply] 
    @eComments NVarChar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.SupplierProductionScheduleReplies 
    SET Comments = @eComments 
    WHERE id = 39906;
END
```

I have hard coded the `id` column value above to simplify the code until I understand what is going wrong - once sorted, this will be passed as a parameter, too.

I have this code I am running from Bizagi, using their modified version of C#:

```cs
//UPDATING FULL PO (PO CHECK)
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519158/executing-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp#50519216
//accessed by MO 20221215
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519158/executing-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp?rq=3
//accessed by MO 20240320
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16
//accessed by MO 20240320

// Set the connection string
var strcnx = CHelper.getParameterValue("SV11SAGE01-StockControl");

// set the variable and value from a form
var eComments = <m_WPC_WeeklyProductChase.idm_WPC_POCheck.eKPComments>
var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

// identify the stored procedure
var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.stpr_WPC_UpdatePOReply");

connection.ConnectionString = strcnx;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// add a parameter, based on the variable eComments
cmd.Parameters.Add("@eComments", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = eComments;

try
{
    // running a stored procedure
    connection.Open();
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(exc)
{
    CHelper.ThrowValidationError(exc);
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

When I run the code I get an error:

> Procedure or function stpr_WPC_UpdatePOReply has too many arguments specified.

I have tried removing the parameters, and just calling the stored procedure with the parameters hard coded in the stored procedure, and the update runs with no issues.

However, when I add in parameters, the code errors. I have about 15 parameters to add in, but I have reduced the code and stored procedure to one and 2 parameters until I can sort out the problem, at which time I will add in the extra ones.

I have looked through lots of articles, and as far as I can see the variable name and data type match (I am assuming `NVarChar 200` specified in the C# is equivalent to `NVarChar(Max)`, the SQL parameter query on the stored procedure suggested in one post gave the following:

```
ParameterName: @eComments; 
DataType: nvarchar;
max_length: 400;
is_output: 0
```

I have tried running with 2 parameters, the other one being a parameter for the record's id.

I have tried using `AddWithValue`. I have tried with and without the `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` line. The column `Comments` is defined in SQL Server as `(nvarchar(max), null)`.

I have checked that the stored procedure name matches - and it works fine if there are no parameters specified.

I have simplified what I am doing as much as possible to reduce the likelihood of silly mistakes and typos, but can't see what I am doing wrong. Originally I was running the query without parameters with no problem, but was warned that this risked SQL injection attack so I am reworking the procedure to run with parameters instead. Any help appreciated. Cheers

Comment: I would check log files using SQL Server Management Studio.  The log files are in the explorer under Management.

Comment: is the C# in the question the actual code that is failing, or is that "like this"? the reason I ask: I've seen people reuse the same command object, adding more parameters than are needed by accident, because it already had some from the previous usage

Comment: OK, thanks @jdweng - I have looked and there are no relevant entries in the log SQL Server Logs - Current. All the entries are about database backups, and no mention of the database I am using, since 20:00 the previous evening.

Comment: Does the connection string in your C# point to the right database(StockControlDemo)?

Comment: Hi @Marc Gravell, that is the actual C# code. I did add the line  cmd.Parameters.Clear();  before the cmd.Parameters.Add ... line, but it did not make any difference. Thanks

Comment: Hi @SoftwareDveloper, yes I am happy that the connection string points to the right database, as without the parameters, the update stored procedure (with hard coded variables) works fine.

Comment: Maybe you can try using SQL Profiler to see what's actually being called?

Comment: `"The SQL table field definition for Comments is (nvarchar(max), null)."` That's nice. But the stored procedure definition limits you to 200 characters, regardless of what will fit in the table.

Comment: @Charlieface the stored procedure definition makes the c# parameter type irrelevant... it'll still truncate larger values. And the `finally` block fills the same purpose as a `using` block, so while the code is unusual it's at least still considered "correct" for the closing the connection.

Comment: When you perform a query of the database from c# you should see a login at time of query in the log file.  Make sure you are connecting to same server with SSMS and the c# app.  Check the connection string with the server you are using with SSMS.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the SqlCommand object is IDisposable, too, and should be cleaned up at the same time as the SqlConnection otherwise it will continue to hold a reference to the connection preventing it from being returned to the pool and from being garbage collected itself.

Comment: That it works when no parameters are specified is strong evidence that the connection string is pointing at an incorrect server, instance or database - or that the stored procedure actually deployed isn't what you think it is. With the stored procedure definition in the question `@Comments` has no default value and must be supplied. If you tried to execute that stored procedure without any parameters it should error with `Procedure or function 'stpr_WPC_UpdatePOReply' expects parameter '@eComments', which was not supplied.`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, @jdweng - thanks. I have rechecked the connection string and am as certain as I can be that it is correct. It is used for other connections and they work fine.  I have executed the stored procedure in SSMS and it does error as you mention above: `Procedure dbo.stpr_WPC_UpdatePOReply, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
Procedure or function 'stpr_WPC_UpdatePOReply' expects parameter '@eComments', which was not supplied.`

Comment: @jdweng - ok, I will have another look at the log files. Cheers

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper -  I will review the sql profiler. Cheers

Comment: So it looks like I am passing the parameter twice somehow - the SQL profiler shows this  `exec dbo.stpr_WPC_UpdatePOReply @eComments=default,@eComments=N'mick test'` 
 - which I am taking to mean I need to remove it's definition somewhere, but I will have to dig deeper to understand where . At least it confirms that the connection string is correct!

Comment: @jdweng, all that I can see in the log files are records of when I start and end the sql profile trace, but nothing covering the stored procedure itself

Comment: What connection string are you using.  I think the issue is the driver being used with the connection string.  You are using Bizagi and the driver has to be compatible with Bizagi

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I am reasonably confident that the connection sting is correct, as the same one works in other processes, and I can see the parameters being passed via the SQL profile trace. Thanks

Comment: Maybe issue is in procedure dbo.SupplierProductionScheduleReplies

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I looked into this deeply years ago  (2006-ish) as a VB.Net developer, because VB did not stack `using` blocks as neatly as C#. It turned out SqlCommand is IDisposable only as an accdient of inheriting from Component... but it never actually does anything (or even causes anything to be done in the Component base) that needs disposing ¯\_(ツ)_/¯